# React Native Data Base

Tags: database, react-native, mobile, cloud, storage

Ok... I am so confused. I am new to React Native and I have created a simple mobile app that shows a list of news (containing a specific image, title, and description). I have a lot of experience with programming most of which comes from game development. I have created many games and I am familiar to cloud storage systems that you update and retrieve data.

Right now I just have a local json file with an array of 'news' Objects and then I loop through this array to show the news posts. Basically, I want to move this json file to somewhere online where the app just retrieves it. This would make it so that the News json file could be edited in order to change, add or remove new news. So, I don't need account or anything. I don't even need to be able to set/update data from the app. I just need a place to store images and files that can be retrieved from the app.

I have tried using the common react native data base systems like sqlite, realm, mongodb, and firebase, but must not understand how they work because they make no sense. Also, it seems like when making a mobile app all of these services require you to setup a backend and start a server, which from what I can tell doesn't work on mobile... It seems logical that there would be a global data base that I could store storage on and just receive it by a simple fetch or network call. Am I totally crazy here ?:) Any help or guidance is super appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For testing, you can use jsonserver, or spin up a server on your local network. But the idea of a global database... that's what a backend is for.

Comment: And so if I use a backend how do I startup that backend on a mobile build?

Comment: You wouldn't, you would host it on a server.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am new to this type of data access so how exactly would I go about doing that? Do you have any tutorials you could link me to for this kind of thing?

Comment: Sure. I don't have any favorite tutorials unfortunately, but if you like Javascript, there are a bunch of Node/ Express/ Mongo tutorials that might be what you need. Heroku has a free hosting tier that you can use for Node apps.